# yii2 model doesnt contain an attribute error

Tags: php, yii2

In my model TblTrucks I have added

```
class TblTrucks extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
 {
  public $rejected_reason;

     public function rules()
      {
      return [
        [['rejected_reason'], 'safe'], 
           ]
     }

 }
```

Now in my controller whenever I try setting the value like

```
$trucks = TblTrucks::find()->all();

foreach($trucks as $key=>$value){
   $value->rejected_reason = "test here"; 

 }

 return $trucks;
```

I am getting an error

> TblTrucks has no attribute named "rejected_reason".

where could I be going wrong?

I have also tried adding a fields array in my model like

```
    public function fields()
    {
      $fields = parent::fields();

       $fields['rejected_reason'] =function ($model){
        return $this->rejected_reason;
       };
     return $fields;

    }
```

Comment: Your query contains fields from db. so, it does not contain public variable.

Comment: How then can i add a new variable to the results.

Comment: is it possible to add the public variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query as below :

```
$trucks = TblTrucks::find()
      ->select('your_table_name.*,"test here" as rejected_reason') // replace with your table name
      ->all();
```